# Member List Pagination Not Working

Tags: forum, discussion

Pagination links appear as expected and urls are fine, however the results dont change depending on which pagination page you are on.

Comment: Please supply more information - Is this in the control panel? Or because you've tagged it with Forum is it within this on the frontend? Version numbers? Example URL for 1st page, Example URL for second (duplicate) page? Are there JS errors in the browser console? Template Tag code?

Comment: Please give us more information and URL/template samples as Peter Lewis has asked and we have a much better chance of helping you out.